# Draw image at x and y position windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to draw an image in a Windows Store app. The image is predrawn in the XAML designer interface.

When clicking on a button, I want it's X and Y coördinates to change randomly; taking the screensize into account.

Googling and trying did get me somewhere. Problem is, however, that the image sometimes disappears off the screen (why I do not know).

How can I change the X and Y position so that the image does not fall off the screen?

What I have tried (some variations too):

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
Random r = new Random();
int y = r.Next(0, (int)bounds.Right);
int x = r.Next(140, (int)bounds.Bottom);
image.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0,0);
```

For reference: The 140 value is the position from the top that the image can not be displayed in.

I know the Thickness-class uses "Left, Top, Right, Bottom" positioning. I am unsure how to randomly calculate the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped your x and y values. Assuming your image is in a panel the size of the window and has `VerticalAlignment="Top"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` you could do this:

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
var r = new Random();
int x = r.Next(0, (int)bounds.Right - (int)image.ActualWidth);
int y = r.Next(140, (int)bounds.Bottom - (int)image.ActualHeight);
image.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, -x, -y);
```

Comment: The image still disappears off the screen. Also you forgot to cast the image.ActualWidth and image.ActualHeight as integers.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot to make it clear what you mean by disappear? Also, what is it inside of?

Comment: The image just disappears, as if it's coördinates make it fly off the screen. I checked the coördinates via debugging and it should actually appear on-screen in those cases when it doesn't. I actually figured it out making that screenshot; I noticed there was a gridrow (the one with the 140-pixels) at the top-layer. Making the image fall behind it when drawing inside that area. So your solution works, thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. In the future - debugging layout issues is best done with a visual tree debugger. For Windows 8 you can use XAML Spy or WinRT XAML Toolkit's debugging tools.